# Getting the text of the first <td> in the same row as another <td>

Tags: jquery

I'm running into a problem more and more often, where I have an event handler tied to a `<td>`, and I need to get the text in the first `<td>` in that row (which is the primary key). What's the easiest way to do that, assuming I don't want to add any additional markup?

Answer (score 4):

Using JQuery you could write something like this:

```
function eventHandler()
{
    var firstTdText = $(this).parent().children("td:first").html();
}
```

Assuming of course, that "this" references the html TD.

Comment: Thanks. I should have tested it. I was thinking CSS selectors.

Answer (score 2):

To reference the first cell in that row, you can select it using the `prevAll` selector:

```
$(this).prevAll("td:last")
```

To get the text from it:

```
$(this).prevAll("td:last").html()
// or,
$(this).prevAll("td:last").text()
```

Answer (score 1):

You would go to the [parent `<tr>`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/parent) and then from the parent [to the 1st child.](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/firstChild)